# How to set multiple Image Well?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsimage

I am new to Cocoa and I now wish to set multiple image to image well.
Here is the code snippet:

```
//--------------show rank 1 image-------------//
int rank1 = rank_fst5[0];
NSString *rank1_path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/Users/Desktop/gallery/%d.png",rank1];
NSImage *image1 = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:rank1_path];
[imageRank1 setImage:image1];



//--------------show rank 2 image-------------//
int rank2 = rank_fst5[1];
NSString *rank2_path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/Users/Desktop/gallery/%d.png",rank2];
NSImage *image2 = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:rank2_path];
[imageRank2 setImage:image2];
```

The result only shows the first image in *"imageRank1"*.
And if I comment the first show image code, I can get the second one on show. But the two images cannot show concurrently.

Could anyone help me? Thanks.

Comment: As a side note, you're not releasing the images you allocate. As for you problem, i'd suggest doing an NSLog() on rank1_path and rank2_path. Also check that the imageRank1 and imageRank2 outlets don't actually point to the same image well. Maybe this will help.

Comment: Thank you a lot! It works after I set "int rank2 = rank_fst5[1]" following the "int rank1" before any setImage. The bug is quite stupid :P. But I don't know why it happens though...